# ASP.NET "application/pdf": code runs only once

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on a SharePoint 2013 site and I've added the ability to save pages in PDF. The PDF conversion is handled by the third party library SelectPdf.
I managed to get everything to work (rendering and file download), except that the "PDF Download" button that I have on my page works only 1 time. Meaning, the click event on the code behind is fired only once, no matter how many times I click the button (notice that I click it with intervals of 10+ seconds). If I want to download the PDF file again, I have to refresh the page.
I put together a "hello world" example (see below) in order to pinpoint the problem:

```cs
protected void lnkPdfDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");

    /************************************ Create PDF File ************************************/
    string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">
                    <html dir=""ltr"" lang=""en-US"">
                    <body><h1>Hello World</h1></body>
                    </html>";
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
    byte[] bytes = doc.Save();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // ALTERNATIVE: doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    /************************************ Create PDF File ************************************/

    //Response.End(); // This throw a ThreadAbortException, therefore I'm using the alternative code below
    Response.Flush();
    Response.SuppressContent = true;
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

At the beginning I thought it was `Response.End()` that caused the issue (by throwing the ThreadAbortException), but I replaced it with other code and I still have the same problem (no exceptions are thrown now).

I don't think the problem is in the SelectPdf library: I can comment out the entire block (between the "Create PDF File" comments), and I still get the same thing (obviously no PDF is generated).

I noticed that, at most, I can successfully click the "download" button up to 2 times (it's rare, and not consistent): the third time nothing happens.

While this isn't a huge deal, I think there is something wrong going on that I'm not seeing. Here is why: after I click the "download" button (and get my PDF file), I am not able to go on edit mode in my SharePoint page. The "loading" message keeps spinning but nothing happens (again, unless I refresh the page).

Has anyone had this problem? I looked online but I couldn't find anything about it.
I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome 51. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are not javascript/jquery errors happening when the download button is clicked that prevent the re-clicking of the PDF button and also going into edit mode?
Especially since refreshing the page makes everything work again.

Comment: I enabled the option to break on all exceptions (in IE) but I don't see any JavaScript errors being thrown. I noticed that if I remove all the Response code, then the event is fired all the time.